# PIxelated lines in illustrator... images are for print, should I worry?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, pixelation

I am working on a big project and have done a few drawings but I am noticing some weird stuff with my strokes and I just wanted to check if it is normal and just something that I am seeing on my screen but want show when printed.

You can see as I zoom in and out the irregularities in the lines change.

If I may ask and second question also, about saving these images for print (using inDesign), should I import the .ai files directly or save as PDF as import those. Are there any pros and cons.

Thank you,

Daniel

[image]

Comment: @Scott Apologies, I forgot I had referred to this in an earlier question. Although it is the same issue, it was (I believe) a very different question. Also that particular part of my question wasn't quite answered in my previous question. I will of course, try and be more vigilant with the content of my questions. Thank you, Dan

Comment: Not a problem Daniel. Regarding the PDF/InDesign - it really doesn't matter. I use native .ai files myself, but PDF (if saved properly) are just as good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are all vector paths, the pixelation you are seeing is merely due to your screen. Screens are much lower resolution than your printer will be so you won't see this pixelation on press.